# PHP regular expression for positive number with 0 or 2 decimal places

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to use the following regular expression to check whether a string is a positive number with either zero decimal places, or 2:

```
^\d+(\.(\d{2}))?$
```

When I try to match this using preg_match, I get the error:

> Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/lib/forms.php on line 862

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is about delimiter missing that is `/` or `#`, etc, make sure that you wrap regex expression in delimiters:

```
if (preg_match('/^\d+(\.(\d{2}))?$/', $text))
{
 // more code
 return true;
}
```

Or:

```
if (preg_match('#^\d+(\.(\d{2}))?$#', $text))
{
 // more code
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Delimiters are not limited to `/` and `#`, you can use any non-alphanumeric (excluding whitespace and backslash) e.g. `*`, `@`, `|`, `!`,..... are all valid delimiters.

Comment: @Sarraz Ahmed: No prob! It's good to know, because the time you're actually searching for `some weird /#/ string` (hey, you'll never know!) you may find it easier to use `!` as a delimiter!! :)

Answer (score 1):

For PHP's `preg` suite of functions, the regexes must be specified with a delimiter, such as `/`; for instance, `/[a-z]/` will match any character from `a` to `z`.  When you give it the string `"^\\d+(.(\\d{2}))?$"`, it wants to treat the regex as `\\d+(.(\\d{2}))?$`, delimited by `^`s, but it can't find the second `^`.  Thus, fixing that is as simple as `"/^\\d+(.(\\d{2}))?$/"`  The other thing you need to fix is the `.`; that's a metacharacter which will match *any* non-newline character; for a literal period, you want `\.`.  This gives you the regex `"/^\d+(\.(\d{2}))?$/"`.  Also, note that if you don't want a capturing group, you can use `"/^\d+(?:\.(\d{2}))?$/"`, which will put the digits after the decimal point in `$1` instead of `$2`.